# which data type can store both number and text at a same time in c#

Tags: c#, types

How I declare a data type that can store both numbers and text at a same time or need a hint on how to do that in c#.

Comment: This sounds like an x/y problem. You'll get better results if you ask about the problem you're trying to solve instead of the solution you came up with.

Comment: `object` can store anything

Comment: Create a type.  Give it two properties.  The first property is a numeric type.  The second is a string.  Where did you have trouble doing this?  Show us.

Comment: use      dynamic/object

Comment: @Amy i have to store a model and serial number of a car which include both number and char like model :  670 EQ and  Serial No.: PMMNDe1000001

Comment: @YogeshBhatt Please edit your question and add a few examples (more than one). If you just mean you want to store "ABC12345", use a string.

Comment: create a class with text and number props?

Comment: @YogeshBhatt Amazingly enough, strings can contain letters and numbers at the same time.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes sounds like that, above is an example. sounds like that works.

Comment: Model number and serial number and phone number are not really numbers.  You cannot add `PMMNDe1000001` and `PMXYDe1000071` and get anything meaningful

Comment: Why don't you just store everything as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string like `PMXYDe1000071` is a string, nothing else would fit this.

More importantly though, a serial number is a business concept (Domain knowledge comes into play). Like most business concepts there usually isn't a data type.

In the case of a serial number for example there is going to be some meaning to each of the parts of the number:

Let's assume we have

1. a Facility
2. a Line
3. the actual number for the product.
4. a serial number should be a 3 character code Facility,
5. A 3 character line,
6. a 10 digit number

We can represent this in code like so:

```
public enum Line
{
    ABC,
    PMV,
    DGE,
    RAR
}

public enum Facility
{
   IWA,
   CHI,
   DET,
   MEX
}

public class Serial
{
    public Line Line { get; set; }
    public Facility Facility { get; set; }
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sequenceString = SequenceNumber.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0');
        return $"{Line.ToString()}{Facility.ToString()}{sequenceString }";
    }
}
```

And then in code we use each object like:

```
    var s2 = new Serial();
    s2.Facility = Facility.MEX;
    s2.Line = Line.PMV;
    s2.SequenceNumber = 50014;

    Console.WriteLine(s2.ToString());
```

A serial object to a string gives you a format you want, but all of the business concepts are still safely in their own objects.

The object above in string format is: `PMVMEX0000050014` but we can still perform logical operations based off of any one property.